# Does Anyone Know of a plugin called jcf javascript custom forms? I cannot find a repo a website or some infos about it

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm looking to find documentation about a plugin called jcf javascript custom forms? I cannot find a repo a website or some infos about it, do someone used this plugin?

Comment: I have heard of jQuery custom forms, but not javascript custom forms

Comment: Hi thanks, I know about that one thanks but mine is jacascript..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, that the online service psd2html.com uses this library for almost all markups they develop. Probably it is self-made lib for their own purposes. I didn't find a documentation yet.

Comment: Sorry for being late but I asked them and this is right

Comment: The script has been publicly released at this page http://psd2html.com/jcf - feel free to play around ;)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's here:

https://github.com/w3co/jcf

And this is filler to reach the minimum character limit for SO.